# Not getting an AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to AJAX so I found a tutorial and hacked it up to fit my PHP code. It's a "like" button tutorial and inside of my code it works okay by adding the "like" count total to the database.

The problem is that once I click the "like", the number of likes doesn't update (on the page).

The original tutorial code works fine, so obviously I did something stupid.

Here's my code for index.php

```
function cwRating(id,type,target){
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'rating.php',
    data:'bt_id='+id+'&type='+type,
    success:function(msg){
        if(msg == 'err'){
            alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
        }else{
            $('#'+target).html(msg);
        }
    }
});
}
```

And this is the spot where it shows the like and like count:

```
<span class="like" onClick="cwRating(<?php echo $row_bt['bt_id']; ?>,1,'like_count<?php echo $row_bt['bt_id']; ?>')"></span>

<span class="counter" id="like_count<?php echo $row_bt['bt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_bt['like_num']; ?></span>
```

This is the entire rating.php page:

```
include_once("likes.php");
$likes = new Likes();
if($_POST['bt_id']){
//previous tutorial data
$prev_record = $likes->get_rows($_POST['bt_id']);
//previous total likes
$prev_like = $prev_record['like_num'];

//calculates the numbers of like or dislike
if($_POST['type'] == 1){
    $like = ($prev_like + 1);
    $return_count = $like;
}else{
    $like = $prev_like;
}

//store update data
$data = array('like_num'=>$like,'like_date'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
//update condition
$condition = array('bt_id'=>$_POST['bt_id']);
//update tutorial like dislike
$update = $likes->update($data,$condition);

//return like or dislike number if update is successful, otherwise return error
echo $update?$return_count:'err';
}
```

I want to have the response in the .counter class, I'm assuming it's just the AJAX code that needs tweaking.

Comment: try add error return in your ajax call, `success:function() {}, error: function(err) { console.log('error', err); }`

Comment: I added that but get nothing.

Comment: please, post the return of the success function, if have, try this `success: function(msg) { console.log(msg); }`

Comment: When I add that, there's no message at all, nothing happens.

Comment: try this `success:function() { alert('return success'); }, error: function(err) { alert('error'); }`

Comment: Ah, ok now I get the alert popup "error".

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an error in your PHP code, use the Google Chrome to see this.

```
1. Right click on your page and then select inspect element;
2. Click on the "Network" tab;
3. Find and click on your ajax request in "Name Path" column (rating.php);
4. Go to "Response" tab;
5. See the response of your ajax request.
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing under the Response tab.

Comment: Please go to tab "Headers", in the General topic has a field Status Code, what is the value of this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I checked the "Network" tab in Chrome and saw a few errors, mainly it was "xmlhttprequest cannot load no 'access-control-allow-origin'". In my AJAX post url I removed the www. from the domain and everything works now.